# yii2 make uploaded files private

Tags: yii2, private

Currently in my `Yii2` app, files are uploaded to the public path `web`. But I need to make those files private. I know it is possible to prevent direct folder access with `.htaccess` but it is still accessible if we type the full url in the browser. Is there any way in `Yii2` to make the files private so that it can be accessible via only controller paths so that we can apply the `Access control` and `RBAC` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

Create uploads folder in Frontend directory:

`root/uploads`

**Controller action**:

> Yii2 Basic App
> @app: Your application root directory
>
> Yii2 Advanced
> @frontend: Alias for your frontend root folder on your root app install directory

Source: [Yii 2 list of path aliases available with default basic and advanced app.](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app)

```
//Basic App create path to folder that can contain user files
$path = \Yii::getAlias('@app/uploads/');

//set UploadedFile $object to property

$model->file = $object;

$model->upload($path);
```

Now we can store any files out from `web` directory;

**Upload model**:
Save method:

```
$this->file->saveAs($path . $this->file->baseName . '.' . $this->file->extension);
```

After that you can use same `$path` var to access thous files from any controller. Also make sure, that you have a configured `.htaccess` file in the root, which points all frontend requests to the `web` directory.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm using the basic yii2 template, if you could modify it for that it will be helpful. I have some private pdf documents which needs to be protected.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC Updated answer